# Get current user outside of Wordpress Multisite

Tags: multisite, users

How to get current logged in user in Wordpress Multisite outside of it?

I tried the method for Wordpress Singlesite and it give the error `Call to a member function set_prefix() on a non-object` on code line `$wpdb->set_prefix( $table_prefix, false );` location `wp-includes/ms-settings.php:196`.

I think there should be a way to do it properly without exporting a bunch of functions from Wordpress.

Piece of code (`$root = ABSPATH . '/sf/app'`):

```
    $root = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir');
    require_once(realpath($root . '/../../wp-load.php'));
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'outside' of it? Are you trying to implement an AJAX endpoint? If so you should never use a standalone file, use the WP AJAX api instead and this problem vanishes. Standalone form and ajax files are major security holes

Comment: I have to use wordpress login system in Symfony framework. The login should be made on Wordpress pages.

Comment: That sounds cumbersome, is there not a WP auth bundle? Your question essentially boils down to "How do I bootstrap/load WordPress in an external script?"

Comment: @TomJNowell, yes, it is.

Comment: Can you provide a more comprehensive example of what you've done so far? Not everybody here knows Symfony and incomplete snippets don't provide a lot of context, it might help

Comment: I just tried to include wp-load.php. The path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including the `wp-load.php` file in your external script ?

```
require_once("/path/to/wordpress/wp-load.php");
```

Comment: Yes I tried this. And it gives the error `Call to a member function set_prefix() on a non-object`.

Comment: Could you please paste here the code you're using to include the     wp-load.php file ? Or any other relevant code, it's hard to help you without some samples of what you've done so far :)

Comment: I updated my question. `$root . '/../../'` is my wordpress folder.

Comment: You can't use the `$wpdb` object without declaring `global $wpdb`

Comment: @TomJNowell, strange, but it helped. You can write an anwer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Your error suggests it's happening in a core WordPress file, which should never be modified under any circumstances. It would be wrong of me to post such an answer

Comment: Instead more information is needed to answer your question